# How to take minimum column value in pandas data frame if values in another column repeat?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
 Col A     Col B     Col C
   1         4         3
   1         4         5
   2         3         7
   2         4         6
   1         6         6
   1         6         4
```

When values in Column B repeat (are consecutive) I want to keep the row with the minimum value in Column C. Such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
 Col A     Col B     Col C
   1         4         3
   2         3         7
   2         4         6
   1         6         4
```

It's okay if values in Column B repeat they just can't be consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
Yourdf=df.sort_values(['ColC']).drop_duplicates(['ColA','ColB']).sort_index()
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     4     3
2     2     3     7
3     2     4     6
5     1     6     4
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers seem to overlook **values in Column B repeat (are consecutive)**, so here's my approach:

```
B_blocks = df['Col B'].ne(df['Col B'].shift()).cumsum()
min_idx = df.groupby(B_blocks)['Col C'].idxmin()

df.loc[min_idx]
```

Output:

```
   Col A  Col B  Col C
0      1      4      3
2      2      3      7
3      2      4      6
5      1      6      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [GroupBy.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g=df['Col_B'].ne(df['Col_B'].shift()).cumsum()
new_df=df.sort_values('Col_C').groupby(g).first().reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
0      1      4      3
1      2      3      7
2      2      4      6
3      1      6      4
```